# DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gnldpbnocfnlkkicnaplmkaphfdnlplb/

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, devtools

Encountered error:
*DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gnldpbnocfnlkkicnaplmkaphfdnlplb/ContentScript/CaptureBrowserEvent.js.map*
Any ideas how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Open chrome settings, search for *"gnldp"* phrase (at the beginning of url in message body).
In my case the extension was unnecessary, so I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in chrome.

I finally realized Adblock was causing this issue.

While waiting for an update of this extension and since I didn't want to disable source maps in the dev tools, I simply disabled in the console the "warnings". As shown below

[chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9GFG.png)